# How to center text - Eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, center

I have set up some text in a textView to explain the commands that the app responds to but the code gets formated (flattened) no matter what i type for gravity. The text is supposed to look like this :

Commands and functions:

- **"left"**- Sets tv gravity to left and changes text.
- **"right"**- Sets tv gravity to right and changes text.
- **"center"**- Sets tv gravity to center and changes text.
- **"blue"**- sets tColor to BLUE.
- **"reset"**- resets all tv properties to default
- **"WTF"**- randomises tSize and tColour

But instead turns out like this :

[image]

And here is my code(TextView is in a linear layout) :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tvTextPlayExplain" 
    android:typeface="serif"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `android:gravity="center"`, and for the text string that you input, you should use the character "\n" to make a newline instead of Enter. For example, the string "This is line 1 \n This is line two" will give you output

```
This is line 1
This is line two
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare the text in the string.xml file like this and you will be able to use html tags to make a list and keep the format :

```
<string name="tvTextPlayExplain">
<![CDATA[
<p>Commands and functions:</p><br/>
<ul>
<li>"left"- Sets tv gravity to left and changes text.</li>
.... and so on
<li>"WTF"- randomises tSize and tColour</li>
</ul>
]]>
</string>
```

and then use :

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.tvTextPlayExplain)));
```